# How to convert nested brackets to a list of pairs

Tags: python

I have code that returns a tuple with nested brackets which represents alternating intervals to exclude and include. The nested tuples look like:

```
((None, 6), 16)
```

and

```
(((None, 1), 6), 16)
```

What I really want is to convert these into a list of pairs for only the parts that are included but it is slightly complicated.  I will give some examples to hopefully explain.

```
((None, 6), 16) should go to [(6, 16)]

(((None, 1), 6), 16) should go to [(0,1), (6, 16)]

((None, 8), 17) should go to [(8, 17)]

(((None, 2), 8), 17) should go to [(0, 2), (8, 17)]

(((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17) should go to [(0, 2), (3, 4), (8, 17)]
```

If the number of open brackets is even the first interval will be an exclude one and so should be omitted. For example:

```
((((None, 2), 4), 5), 6) should go to [(2, 4), (5, 6)]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I must ask, is it necessary for the intervals to be represented this way in the first place?

Comment: @Gaberocksal Thank you. Sadly it's the way the code I have to use makes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a case where matching can be used as an alternative. It may not be as efficient, but the logic seems more clear:

```
def parse_intervals(seq):
    match seq:
        case (None, n):
            return [(0, n)]
        case ((None, n), m):
            return [(n, m)]
        case ((tuple(seq), n), m):
            return [*parse_intervals(seq), (n, m)]
        case _:
            raise ValueError('An invalid data structure has been transmitted')
```

Comment: This is a beautiful piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this iterative solution. The key is to start from the right and work leftwards until you hit a `None`.

```py
tests = {
    ((None, 6), 16): [(6, 16)],
    (((None, 1), 6), 16): [(0, 1), (6, 16)],
    ((None, 8), 17): [(8, 17)],
    (((None, 2), 8), 17): [(0, 2), (8, 17)],
    (((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17): [(0, 2), (3, 4), (8, 17)],
}


def parse_intervals(intervals):
    output = []

    while intervals:
        intervals, right = intervals

        if intervals is None:
            left = 0
        else:
            intervals, left = intervals

        output.insert(0, (left, right))

    return output


for example, expected in tests.items():
    print(example, parse_intervals(example) == expected)
```

output:

```
((None, 6), 16) True
(((None, 1), 6), 16) True
((None, 8), 17) True
(((None, 2), 8), 17) True
(((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17) True
```

Comment: Thank you. The insert(0,..)  makes me uncomfortable but I guess its OK if the lists are really short.

Comment: @Simd Array shifts are extremely performant, it doesn't concern me at all. If you must avoid it, you could build the list forwards and reverse it afterwards (O(n) instead of O(n^2))

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17)

#convert to string; remove the characters '[', ']' and replace None with 0
t = str(t).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('None','0')

#connvert to list
t = t.split(',')

#convert the values to numbers
t = [int(x) for x in t]

#If the length is odd remove 0
if len(t) % 2 == 1:
    t.remove(0)

#a new list
l = [(n, m) for n, m in zip(t[::2], t[1::2])]

print(l) #output: ((0, 2), (3, 4), (8, 17))

# case 2: if input is t = (((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17), 8):
#the output is : [(2, 3), (4, 8), (17, 8)]

#Edit:
#Method-2:
t = (((((None, 2), 3), 4), 8), 17)
x, l = 0, []

while x >= 0:
    if not isinstance(t[0], tuple):
        l.insert(0,t[0])
        l.insert(1,t[1])
        break
    for y in t:
        if isinstance(y, tuple):t = y
        else : l.insert(0, y)
    x += 1
if len(l) % 2 == 0: l[l.index(None)] = 0
else: del l[l.index(None)]
result = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i % 2 == 1: result.append((l[i-1], l[i]))
print(result)
```

Comment: IMO you can replace the last for-loop with `[(n, m) for n, m in zip(t[::2], t[1::2])]`

Comment: BTW transforming to string may not work well if the type of numbers is a bit weird. Also you're limiting numbers to only one type. On top of that, new problems may arise because of [limitations on transforming str to int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#integer-string-conversion-length-limitation).

Comment: 1. Edited as per your request.2, I think 4300 is the maximum numbers of characters which can be converted from str to int which seems to be a decent anumber

Comment: I think, it's better to avoid transforming numbers into a string and vice versa. It's fun, of course, but unreliable and slow as well. Instead, I'd suggest flattening with help of recursion as far as we have a simple regular data structure. E.g. `flat = lambda x: [0] if x is None else [*flat(x[0]), x[1]]`. Then all the code can look like `s = flat(data); s = s[len(s) % 2:]; s = [(n, m) for n, m in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])]`. We preserve the type of numbers and save time converting them to a string and back.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I've edited and added another answer as method-2. I made this yesterday and posting now after a bit of hesitation(as it involves more steps comparatively.). Check my another an without converting into string.